# How can I customize Google Chart Editor

Tags: charts

I'm using google chart in a asp.net project, I used chart Wrapper to draw charts.
and I enable chart Editor to allow use edit the chart and customize the chart.

What I need is, how to customize the Chart Editor panel. I mean change the setting of warring message and the example shown, control the allowed customize charts.

Here is a screenshot of what I need to customize:

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: This question should be posted to the Google product forums, not here.

Comment: Why not here Till Helge?,

Comment: Because we cannot provide support for any software product out there. That's totally impractical. And you are most likely better off asking the guys who actually created a software, instead of some people who might or might not have some experience with it.